# check if email is valid or not

Tags: python

Develop a python script to check whether a given input email id (in the form of string) is a valid email id or not without using built-in functions and regular expressions. Valid email addresses must follow these rules:

a. It must have the username@websitename.extension format type.

b. The username can only contain letters, digits and underscores.

c. The website name can only have letters and digits.

d. The maximum length of the extension is three characters.

so i did this

```
def p(n):
    a,b=n.split("@")
    c,d=b.split(".")
    # print(n,a,c,d)

    # a=username ,c=website,d=com
    a=list(a)
    c=list(c)
    d=list(d)

    print(a,c,d)
    alp="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
    g=list(alp)
    l=["_"]
    m=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    m=list(m)
    print(g,l,m)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] not in g or l or m:
            print("invalid ")
            return
    for i in range(len(c)):
        if c[i] not in g or m:
            print("invalid")
            return
    for i in range(len(d)): 
        if d[i] not in g or len(c)!=3:
            print("invalid")
            return
    print("valid")



n=input()
p(n)
```

all i get as output is invalid. what did i do wrong?

some suggested me to make some changes

```py
def p(n):
    a,b=n.split("@")
    c,d=b.split(".")
    # print(n,a,c,d)

    # a=username ,c=website,d=com
    a=list(a)
    c=list(c)
    d=list(d)

    print(a,c,d)
    alp="qwertyuiopasdfghjklzxcvbnm"
    g=list(alp)
    l=["_"]
    m=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,0]
    m=list(map(str,m))
    print(g,l,m)
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[i] not in g or a[i] not in l or a[i] not in  m:
            print("invalid ")
            return
    for i in range(len(c)):
        if c[i] not in g or c[i] not in  m:
            print("invalid")
            return
    for i in range(len(d)): 
        if d[i] not in g or len(c)!=3:
            print("invalid")
            return
    print("valid")

n=input()
p(n)
```

it still gives the same output

Comment: `if a[i] not in g or l or m:` doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: Please use meaningful variable names.

Comment: Why do you think you need `m = list(m)`? it's already a list.

Comment: what does it do? and what should i do ?

Comment: You should do `a[i] not in g or a[i] not in l or a[i] not in m`

Comment: Or use `if any(a[i] not in x for l in (g, l, m)):`

Comment: Also, the values in `m` are integers.  Integers are not the same thing as characters.  `1` is not the same as `"1"`.

Comment: @Rahul What it does is check: `a[i] not in g` OR `l` OR `m`. That means that the last two clauses check `if l` and `if m`. The truthiness of a list is non-emptiness, and both are non-empty, so it's always True.